# Missing encodings in Python lxml on Windows

Tags: python, windows, lxml

I'm trying to run this little bit of code in Python 2.7 on Windows, using lxml 2.3.

```
from lxml import etree
p = etree.XMLParser(encoding='cp1252')
```

which returns

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: 'cp1252'
```

From what I understand, lxml uses libxml2, which in turn depends on libiconv for handling character encoding such as this one.  However, only basic encodings such as ascii or utf-8 are working.

Does anyone have an idea why I'm unable to use other encodings?  Is libiconv not being loaded somehow, even though it should be included in the lxml binary package?

Thanks!

---

**Solved:**

I solved this by uninstalling my 64-bit version of Python for Windows and installing the 32-bit version, along with the 32-bit binary build of lxml 2.3.  It's not clear what the problem was, but I suspect that the 64-bit binary build of lxml didn't include libiconv or was unable to link to it somehow.

Thanks to everyone who read this and tried to help!

Comment: Does `'a'.decode('cp1252')` work in your Python shell?

Comment: Please create a proper answer and mark it as accepted so that this question no longer shows as unanswered.  Thanks.